# How to pass a contiguous array as a parameter in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have created a contiguous array with random values (0-9), but I don't know how to pass it to a function that would print it.

Right now I'm simply iterating through the array inside the main function, whenever I need to print it. But I want to have a function for that, it would make my code cleaner.

A minimal code example is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **alloc_2d_int(int rows, int cols);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int **matrix;
    int i,j,size=3;
    matrix = alloc_2d_int(size,size);

    // generate the array
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    // how I print the array right now
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d][%d]=%d\n", i,j,matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // this is how I want the printing to happen
    print_arr(matrix,3);
}

int **alloc_2d_int(int rows, int cols) {
    int *data = (int *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));
    int **array= (int **)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);
    return array;
}

void print_arr(int **array,int size)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            printf("matrix[%d][%d]=%d\n", i,j,array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error message:**
conflicting types for ‘print_arr’ [enabled by default]

Comment: If you add a prototype for your `print_arr` function, your code will work: http://ideone.com/qMQqtK

Comment: Or... move `print_arr` function above `main`. Basically, compiler parses source file from top to bottom, and you either need to provide forward declarations, or move function definitions *before* they actually are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add the **declaration(prototype)** of your function. In C language, by-default, the return type of a function is of `int` type. But for your `print_arr()` function, the return type is `void`. So, you get the conflict type error.

So, Declare the `print_arr()` function above the `main()` function. Like:

```
void print_arr(int **array,int size);
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared `print_arr` function before the main so it is not able to find it. Rest works smoothly.

Comment: gcc or g++ compiler